# Display a message in the font type and size selected by the user from two listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have been working on this project for a few days, it’s a C# Windows Visual Studio 2010 form and I have been posting different questions that relate to the same project; as I was told to post different questions instead on having them all in the same post. So this is the project: create a form with two ListBoxes—one contains at least four font names and the other contains at least four font sizes. Let the first item in each list be the default selection if the user fails to make a selection. Allow only one selection per ListBox. After the user clicks a button, display "Hello" in the selected font and size. 
This time I’m having a problem getting the message in the textbox to display according to the font type and size that the user selected. Here is where I’m at in the coding:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //populate listbox1
        listBox1.Items.Add("Arial");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Calibri");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Times New Roman");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Verdana");

        //populate listbox2
        listBox2.Items.Add("8");
        listBox2.Items.Add("10");
        listBox2.Items.Add("12");
        listBox2.Items.Add("14");

        this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; // <--- set default selection for listBox1 

        this.listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0; // <--- set default selection for listBox2

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello!"; 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Now I'm trying to elicit a call from a button clicked that will display the message "Hello" in the user’s choice of font and font size. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried for setting the font? So far, you seem to have just omitted that part in your code; have you looked into the docs on `TextBox`-related members named something with `Font`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this method:

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "Hello!"; 
}
```

in the button_click event of your button, add this :

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    textBox1.Text = "hello";       
    textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));  
    }
```

you might want to remove the  `selectedindexchanged` methods in your code if you are going to use a button tho. depends on what you want.

edit:

```
 public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Arial");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Calibri");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Times New Roman");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Verdana");

        listBox2.Items.Add("8");
        listBox2.Items.Add("10");
        listBox2.Items.Add("12");
        listBox2.Items.Add("14");
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    textBox1.Text = "hello";       
    textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));  
    }
```

if you just use the above code everything should work as you want it to. I tried it out myself and it's working fine for me

Comment: Hi again, I am currently trying this and will be right back. Thanks

Comment: I now have this error message:
 'FontForm.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'textBox1_TextChanged' and no extension method 'textBox1_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'FontForm.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: in your form, remove the textbox control and just add a new one. make sure it has the same name --> "textBox1".

Answer (score 1):

This was my final submission. Thanks for all of the advice guys.

```
    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        //populate listbox1 
        listBox1.Items.Add("Arial"); 
        listBox1.Items.Add("Calibri"); 
        listBox1.Items.Add("Times New Roman"); 
        listBox1.Items.Add("Verdana");
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; // <--- set default selection for listBox1

        //populate listbox2
        listBox2.Items.Add("8"); 
        listBox2.Items.Add("10"); 
        listBox2.Items.Add("12"); 
        listBox2.Items.Add("14");
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0; // <--- set default selection for listBox2
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        textBox1.Text = "hello";        
        textBox1.Font = new Font(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()));   
    } 

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 
}
```

}